# Como sacar los datos de la tabla y muestra en pantalla?

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1 - Muestra en pantalla cuantos alumnos suspendieron cada asignación.

2 - Realiza la media de las notas de cada alumno.

3 - Muestra por pantalla los nombres de los alumnos que obtuvieron media superior a 5.

```py
asignaturas = ["Latín", "Castellano", "Francés", "Inglés"]

alumno1 = [8, 8, 9, 4]

alumno2 = [7, 6, 7, 2]

alumno3 = [10, 7, 8, 9]

alumno4 = [4, 4, 3, 2]

alumno5 = [9, 8, 9, 6]

sum(alumno2) / len(alumno2)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero debes ser mas especifico, muéstranos que has intentado, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) un saludo.

Comment: asignaturas = ["Latín", "Castellano", "Francés", "Inglés"]

alumno1 = [8, 8, 9, 4]
alumno2 = [7, 6, 7, 2]
alumno3 = [10, 7, 8, 9]
alumno4 = [4, 4, 3, 2]
alumno5 = [9, 8, 9, 6]

sum(alumno2) / len(alumno2)

Comment: Hiciste bien en mostrarnos lo que intentaste, pero el código no se ve bien en los comentarios. Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código allí por favor? El boton editar está abajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas. Puedes darle formato al código seleccionando todo el código y presionando las {} arriba de la caja de texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Estructura de datos**

```
asignaturas = ["Latín", "Castellano", "Francés", "Inglés"]

alumnos = {
    'alumno1':[8, 8, 9, 4],
    'alumno2':[7, 6, 7, 2],
    'alumno3':[10, 7, 8, 9],
    'alumno4':[4, 4, 3, 2],
    'alumno5':[9, 8, 9, 6]
}
```

Para los datos de los **alumnos** creas un diccionario cuya **clave** es el nombre del alumno y el **valor** es una lista con sus notas.

Con esta estructura puedes ir recorriendo la lista `asignaturas` y el diccionario `alumnos`.

`alumnos['alumno1']` da como resultado la lista con las notas de ese alumno `[8, 8, 9, 4]`.

Espero te sirva de ayuda para poder empezar, si tienes problemas para resolverlo te voy ampliando la respuesta.

**Ampliación**

***1 - Muestra en pantalla cuantos alumnos suspendieron cada asignación.***

Para cada `asignatura` debes recorrer el diccionario de `alumnos` y comprobar si la nota es menor de 5.

- Recorrer la lista por el valor de sus indices:

  `for i in range(len(asignaturas))`
- Recorrer un diccionario.

  `for alumno in alumnos`. Obtienes la lista de notas de cada alumno
- Comparar cada nota sea menor de 5

  `if alumnos[alumno][i] < 5`

Basicamente será lo mismo para todos los ejercicios.

```
#   opción 1. Solo a nivel de investigación
for i in range(len(asignaturas)):
    print(f'Suspensos en {asignaturas[i]} ==> { sum( 1 for alumno in alumnos if alumnos[alumno][i] < 5 ) }   ')

#   opción 2
for i in range(len(asignaturas)):
    cont = 0 #  Contador de suspensos
    for alumno in alumnos:
        if alumnos[alumno][i] < 5:
            cont += 1

    print(f'Suspensos en {asignaturas[i]} => {cont}')

#   2 - Realiza la media de las notas de cada alumno.

for alumno in alumnos:
    print(f'Media de {alumno} => {sum( alumnos[alumno])/len(alumnos[alumno]):.2f}')

#   3 - Muestra por pantalla los nombres de los alumnos que obtuvieron media superior a 5.

for alumno in alumnos:
    if sum(alumnos[alumno])/len(alumnos[alumno]) > 5:
        print(alumno)
```

Comment: Hola puedes ayudarme, aún no soy capaz @TomyGijon